# How to convert Verilog (.v) project to EDIF(.edf) format?

Tags: verilog

I have very poor verilog knowledge, but i need to convert Verilog project, containing some .v files and folders wth .v files to one large EDIF file for parcing.
Is there any easy way to do this?
I have found iverilog tool, but not sure how to convert all project with subfolders at once. 
Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- EDIF (Electronic Design Interchange Format) is a vendor-neutral format in which to store Electronic netlists and schematics. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EDIF .
- Verilog is a Hardware Description Language, which can describe hardware at a higher, behavioural level of abstraction.

So, in general at least, the two are not compatible. So, in general, you will need to convert your Verilog to gate-level in order for it to be suitable for EDIF. The tool that converts Verilog to gate-level is a *logic synthesiser* and most, if not all, logic synthesisers will be able to output your netlist as an EDIF file.

So,

- if your Verilog is not already gate-level, you will need a logic synthesiser. If you're doing an FPGA design, that will be your FPGA tool: Quartus, Vivado etc.
- if your Verilog is already gate-level, then there may be other, more basic, tools that convert from one to another; I don't know. But, if your Verilog is already gate-level, a logic synthesiser will also be able to do the conversion.